# seekbar thumb position not equals progress

Tags: android, seekbar

I want to create seekbar with thumb which don't change progress. Progress in my seekbar must to setting separately from thumb position. How can I do it?

I should say, I must to extends Seekbar and to override some methods. But I don't understand which??? Which method is determining position of thumb? And which is determining progress?

```
Please help me!!
Thanks at advance!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using different `drawbles`
Let me show you an example :

Your `code`
.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private SeekBar seekBar1;

    private SeekBar seekBar2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         seekBar1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
         seekBar2 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
         seekBar1.setProgress(15);
         seekBar2.setProgress(55);
         Drawable ii = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ii);
        // Drawable iii = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ii);
         seekBar1.setThumb(ii);
         seekBar2.setThumb(ii);

    }



}
```

Your problem:

[image]

what you can do is `simple` just rename the same drawable like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private SeekBar seekBar1;

    private SeekBar seekBar2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         seekBar1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
         seekBar2 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
         seekBar1.setProgress(15);
         seekBar2.setProgress(55);
         Drawable ii = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ii);
         Drawable iii = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ii);
         seekBar1.setThumb(ii);
         seekBar2.setThumb(iii);

    }



}
```

And that's the result:

[image]

Hope that helps!!:)